# How can we choose the most efficient base for radix sort if we are given an array of n numbers and m is the largest number in the array?

Tags: radix-sort

If we are given an array of n numbers, and m is the largest number in the array, and we want to use radix sort to sort this array then how do we choose the base for this radix sort to make it time and memory efficient? How does the size of the array or the largest number of the array help us choose the base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is processor specific, related to internal cache, and the way the cache is implemented. In the case of X86 processors there may be 3 or 4 levels of cache, and usually these are 8 way associative.

Some processors are also sensitive to the location of code in tight loops. On my system, I've seen up to 40% difference in run time on identical code, where the only difference is nops between functions I used to align them to even or odd 16 byte boundaries.

For using radix sort on 32 or 64 bit unsigned integers, base 256 seems to be the best. I ran benchmark for sorting 36 million psuedo random 64 bit unsigned integers, using bit field sizes of {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8} (base 256) taking 8 passes. I tried using {11,11,11,11,10,10} (base 2048 or 1024) taking 6 passes and it took twice as long (~2 seconds versus ~1 second), an issue related to how the cache is implemented on my processor. I also tried {16,16,16,16} (base 65536), 4 passes, and it took almost 2.5 seconds.

There can be consideration for relatively small values of *m*. If *m* is <= 65536, then a radix sort base 256 (2^8) can be done in 2 passes. If sorting integers and *m* is small enough, then a single pass counting sort that generates the sorted output based on counts rather than actually sorting data is faster.